# Cant view events from database on my fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is my JS code. On startup the calendar is visible but after adding to the `events[]` array the calendar disappears. Could someone please help me understand what is going on.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#sectionview').fullCalendar({
          schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
          defaultDate: new Date(y, m, d),

          defaultView: 'agendaWeek',    
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
          minTime: '07:00:00',
          maxTime: '22:00:00',

          events: [{
              id: <?php echo $events['id']; ?>,
              course: <?php echo $events['course']; ?>,
              room: <?php echo $events['room']; ?>,
          },
        ]

          select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('dddd HH:mm'));
            $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('dddd HH:mm'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
          },
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: `after adding to the events[] array` - what does this mean, exactly? How are you adding events?  Also, are `course` and `room` numeric, or strings?  If strings, you need to quote them.

Comment: your events need to have, at minimum, the "id", "title" and "start" values populated, otherwise no events will show in the calendar. This is stated clearly in the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Comment: But as Don't Panic says, the most likely issue is that you haven't put quote marks round your values - so PHP will output these values and create invalid JavaScript, because you're injecting them as literals instead of strings. `events: [{
              id: "<?php echo $events['id']; ?>",
              course: "<?php echo $events['course']; ?>",
              room: "<?php echo $events['room']; ?>",
          }` should do it. (You might not need the quotes round `id` if it's outputting a number)

Comment: And you also need a comma after the `]` which closes the `events` option. Did you check your browser's console? You should have seen these various syntax errors appear.

Comment: so i have found the reason. the event wont plot when using   


`$('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('dddd HH:mm'));`

but if i use


`$('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));`


it displays. But i need to view the Day not the date